# Defining a function to call within axScatter.plt

Tags: python, matplotlib, astronomy

I'm currently working on defining a mathematical function, i.e.,

```
from numpy import tanh

def stravinska(Z, eps=0.5):
    return ((-0.86928)+(0.052481*Z))*(tanh(((2.66503)-(4.44255*Z))))-1.251617

SII   = np.linspace(-3.0, 0.20)
```

To call within

```
axScatter_middle.plot(SII, stravinska(Z=0.5), '-k')
```

However, the following error is return upon compilation:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

I'm scratching my head as to where I have gone wrong as I have used this method successfully many times before. What does this error mean and how can I rectify this problem?

I'm essentially trying to plot the equation 10 from this paper: [Semi-empirical analysis of Sloan Digital Sky Survey galaxies – III. How to distinguish AGN hosts](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?2006MNRAS.371..972S&data_type=PDF_HIGH&whole_paper=YES&type=PRINTER&filetype=.pdf)

Comment: Within your function you don't actually use the value `log_SII_Ha`. I assume this is a mistake? As the only thing you use is `eps` which is a float so it'll return a float. Then you effectively try to plot a float against an array.

Comment: Sorry, I was using the old code. Please see the update.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from numpy import tanh

def stravinska(log_SII_Ha, eps=0):
    strav = ((-30.787)+(1.1358*(log_SII_Ha))+(0.27297*((log_SII_Ha)**2)))*(tanh(5.7409*      (log_SII_Ha)))-31.093
return strav

SII   = np.linspace(-3.0, 0.20)

axScatter_middle.plot(SII, stravinska(SII), '-k')
```